# PHP: How many ways to format data from MySQL with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So far I've seen two ways to format data retrieved from the MySQL database.

Quick Summary of both codes:
When using an Ajax function call which opens a php file which retrieves MySQL data, should it process the MySQL data in that same php file or process the data returned from the php file in the Ajax function which opened said php file?

The first way I believe is the most common way I've seen on tutorials and it looks like this...

PHP FILE

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
  echo "<p class='group_name'>" . $row[0] . "</p>";
}
```

FILE WITH AJAX

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 or xmlhttp.state === 200){
     document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
```

Or this is the other way. It first sends the data to the file with ajax, uses the split() string method, loops through it, uses the split method again, and then formats it with HTML.

SECOND PHP FILE

```
$data = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
  $data .= $row[0] . "|" . $row[1] . "|" . $row[2] . "||"; // adding | and || to be split later
}
```

SECOND FILE WITH AJAX

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 or xmlhttp.state === 200){
     var data = "";
     var data_array = xmlhttp.responseText.split('||'); 

     for(var row = 0; row < data_array.length ;row++){
        var data_row = data_array[row].split('|'); // Taking each value in the array and splitting it again, this time by |
          data = "<p class='group_name'>" + data_row[0] + "</p><span>" + data_row[1] +
        "</span>"
     }
 }
}
```

Which method is better or faster? Or does it not matter? The second one first sends the responseText with only data, so I'm thinking it might speed things up? Then the HTML formatting is done on the client side.

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you mean: In an Ajax function call which opens a php file which retrieves MySQL data, should you process the MySQL data in that same php file or process the data returned from the php file in the Ajax function which opened said php file?

Comment: Check out the php function `json_encode()`; you pass it an array of data, it outputs a JSON encoded object that javascript can deal with directly.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I mean. Maybe I should have asked the question your way...It's a lot more simple. Do you mind if I copy it and paste it above in my question?

Comment: By the way, I process in the php file. My reason is more mundane; if I'm retrieving data in the php file, it is easier for me to keep track of the data by processing it in the php file, right by the SELECT, INSERT, etc. query. I also don't have to keep toggling between php file and javascript file

Comment: hmm, okay. Makes sense for convenience. I'm also going to check out the json_encode() function, it looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting should be done on the client side, that allows you to reuse the same code for different items/pages of your site, and the server should return JSON objects.

That also saves bandwidth (extremely important for mobile devices), for example if we use your first solution and we have 100k rows, we'll also have HTML formatting for each of these rows, which is quite a bit of data.

Also that will allow you to change the design of your page only by editing the page without touching anything on the server side code.